# Error in deploying app to heroku (spring boot)

Tags: java, spring, heroku

So what I'm trying to do is to deploy my Spring Boot App to Heroku (using Git and Heroku CLI).

But every time I push my repo to Heroku, these errors appear after I used "$git push heroku master" in my terminal.

````
    remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.2:repackage (repackage) on project UserEditor: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.2:repackage failed: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]
remote:        [ERROR] 
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR] 
remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
remote: 
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 33efb1c07b67aebd548c83b47099d3a66a2efed2
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 33efb1c07b67aebd548c83b47099d3a66a2efed2
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to myhome-app-1.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/myhome-app-1.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myhome-app-1.git' ```
````

Answer (score 4):

The error would be because you are using Java version above 8 and for free deployment Heroku only allows Java version-8. so in pom.xml change the java version to 8 and rebuild maven. After that, run the project in your local system just to verify there are no errors because Java-8 doesn't contain all the functions that you would have used in your project.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for your answer, as I'm still new to the whole programming world, I'm not really sure how I do it. Do you have maybe a tip for a good video to watch about this?